# jest.mock - Cannot find module in React test file

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I want to mock broadcast-channel in my test case and was following the jest documentation on how to mock a module. However when I run the test, I get an error 'Cannot find module 'BroadcastChannel' from 'broadcast.test.js''

I tried looking at the githubs of both jest and broadcast-channel for similar issues but nothing came up.

Inside broadcast.test.js

```
import BroadcastChannel from 'broadcast-channel';

jest.mock('BroadcastChannel');
```

It should run the test case using the mock broadcast-channel. However, I only get the error:

```
'Cannot find module 'BroadcastChannel' from 'broadcast.test.js''
```

Comment: Have you tried with jest.mock('broadcast-channel') ? Moreover I think you're trying to mock a third-part module. There is a specific folder structure to mock libraries. Check [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks)

Comment: @Andrea-codemillers.com - I tried that and it worked, but the coverage of my test files drops. How would this change effect the creation of new BroadcastChannels?

Comment: @h-manner Tried excluding "__mocks__" folders from your statistics?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a *setupTests* file, where you can create a manual mock for the BroadcastChannel and set it for the window.

```
if (!window.BroadcastChannel) window.BroadcastChannel = BroadcastChannelMock;
```

This applies when you use *react-scripts test* for running tests.